# Laravel - Unable to make PHP-Vars-To-Js-Transformer package work

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-facade

I'm new to Laravel 5 and I was trying to set up [PHP-Vars-To-Js-Transformer](https://github.com/laracasts/PHP-Vars-To-Js-Transformer)
.The problem is, that I'm unable to use **JavaScript** facade in my controller. This class is not found.

**My Controller:**

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;

class HomeController extends Controller
{



public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth');
}

public function index()
{
    $ch = curl_init();
    // Disable SSL verification
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    .....
    return view('home',compact('decodedJSON','encodedMainArray'));
}

  }
```

**My // app/config/app.php**

```
'providers' => [
'...',
'Laracasts\Utilities\JavaScript\JavascriptServiceProvider'
];
```

I've also run commands `php artisan vendor:publish` and `composer install`.
I don't know, if I'm missing something special..
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've figured it out. The problem was in namespacing. The solution was to add `use Laracasts\Utilities\JavaScript\JavaScriptFacade as JavaScript;` at the beginning of the controller file.

Answer (score 1):

To use the facasde like that, add it to your aliases in `config/app.php`:

```
'JavaScript' => 'Laracasts\Utilities\JavaScript\JavaScriptFacade'
```

Comment: Thank You, but this didn't work. Laravel is still unable to recognize this class. Even PhPStorm says "Undefined class JavaScript"

Answer (score 0):

Use these lines at the beginning of the controller. I found this

use Laracasts\Utilities\JavaScript\JavaScriptFacade;
use JavaScript;